# conEmu windows shell command

Tags: windows, shell, console, conemu

I recently found out about conEmu and I find it very useful.
There are however at least two features I find are lacking, and I wondered if there is a way to set them:

1. When I scroll up, if I left click on the console, it goes all the way back down. I don't want this. This could probably be solved by always having the copy/paste mode on (which I can manually set by pressing the alt key).
2. There is no horizontal scroll bar. Instead, the text is truncated at the end of a line, and starts at the next one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Console goes back down only when cursor position is changed. Thats may happens (by left click) when option "Change prompt text cursor position with Left Click" is enabled without any modifier. Also, you may switch console to alternative mode (icon "Lock" on toolbar) which will "pause" you output.
2. Horizontal scrolling is in ConEmu's [roadmap](http://code.google.com/p/conemu-maximus5/wiki/RoadMap).